# echom a multline message, and force pause

Tags: echo, message

I got some code that `jobstart()` a ripgrep, but if there is an error I wish to show it.
At the `on_exit` callback a summary message is `echom`'ed after whether it was successfull or not.

Unfortunately I only ever see the exit summary message, not the "error" message from `SearchOnStderr` below:
Note: The reason I am not using "echoerr" is because I don't wish to have the line number and some other info printed (however echoerr does pause the messages to one can read it). Although `echo` can print multiline, it is not added to the `:messages`, hence I did not use that either.

If I use an `input` (like below), then I only see the `"Press <ENTER> ..."`.

```
let dummy = input("Press <ENTER> ...")
```

`:h echo-redraw` talks about using redraws to prevent losing messages. But I have never gotten `redraw` to help at all.

```
function! myautoload#SearchOnStderr(job_id, data, event)
    let height_bak = &cmdheight
    set cmdheight=12
    redraw
    echom "SEARCH ERROR, job_id:".a:job_id." event:".a:event
    echohl errormsg
    for errorLine in a:data
        echom errorLine
    endfor
    echohl normal
    " ... WAIT HERE for enter to be pressed ...
    exe "set cmdheight=".height_bak
endfun
```

Desired output (With maybe a press enter to continue after it) is shown in the image below. This message is displayed too fast to read, so one has to look at `:messages` to read it:
[image]

EDITS: Adding requested additional info. Yes I'm using Neovim.
Here's some of parts of the code of interest:

```
function! myautoload#SearchInFiles()
    let g:searchString = input('Search in Files '.getcwd().': ')
    let g:search_errors = 0
    let rg_cmd = 'rg -H --no-heading --column --line-number --smart-case '.g:searchString

    " Clear the quickfix of entries
    silent copen " Must be first so over operate on quickfix window
    let title = " ".g:searchString. "     Command: ".rg_cmd
    let context = {'cmd' : rg_cmd}
    call setqflist([], ' ', {'title' : title, 'context' : context})
    echom "--------------------------------------------------"
    echom "About to start job..."
    let opts_dict = {'on_exit': 'myautoload#SearchOnExit', 'on_stdout': 'myautoload#SearchOnStdout', 'on_stderr': 'myautoload#SearchOnStderr'}
    let terminal_buf_nr = jobstart(rg_cmd, opts_dict)
endfunction



function! myautoload#SearchOnExit(job_id, data, event)
    " Refer to :h getqflist-examples*
    let num_entries = getqflist({'size' : 0}).size

    if g:search_errors
        echom "Complete with ERRORS. ".num_entries." entries for: ".g:searchString
    else
        echom "COMPLETE. ".num_entries." entries for: ".g:searchString
    endif
endfun
```

Comment: Why do you reset the height of the command-line to 12?

Comment: If you call that function directly (providing dummy data) do the a:data lines show up? Your sure that a:data has printable content when sent from jobexit?

Comment: @BLayer There is printable data cause I can see it in :messages

Comment: @user938271 So one can see the whole error message. Was something I tried, probably not helpful.... Hopefully the command window height auto grows if one displays the message correctly.

Comment: Ok. I don't see  that in the question. That's an important detail so you might want to update  the question

Comment: @run_the_race You don't need to reset the height of the command-line for that.  Try this: https://0x0.st/ijCn.txt

Comment: There is not enough information in the question: Vim or Neovim? What is `jobexit()` (can't find this function in the help)? How is the job started and with which options? Basically, a simple and complete example. In any case, you can't have the desired hit-enter prompt if  height of the command-line is increased too much.  Besides, if you have several callbacks each displaying their own message, the last one may erase the message of the previous one.

Comment: Finally, if you're using Nvim, there is a known issue which prevents a callback from printing a multi-line message (https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/5067).

Comment: @user938271 that was the first think I tried, it unfortunately doesnt work. Might be due to bug you mention below because of NeoVim. Sorry Its the `on_exit` param of jobstart, I added code to show that now.

Comment: Usually async plugin writers do use file logging or global list variable to store messages and show/inspect them whenever they want.

Comment: @MaximKim This error message is ment to be shown to the user if they pass incorrect parameters onto ripgrep, ie its not just for debugging.